# How can I use a local notification plugin for phonegap?

Tags: cordova, plugins, notifications

I want to use a local notification plugin for my phonegap app,
Which plugin can i use and what is the main steps to follow?

Answer (score 0):

"cordova-plugin-local-notifications" can be used to implement local push notification the installation, its functionality with sample code are well [explained here.](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications)

Comment: I have followed steps as shown in https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications (the installation and  a quick overview) but the plugin doesn't work for me, i have even install the sample given on this link https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/11.-Samples and it doesn't work too. can you help me to figure out what i am messing up?